# Linux console remote applications

Tags: linux, ssh, console

I used to have my PC setup so I could login from home and run a program(which I thought was screen) and run a separate window in a terminal window.  For example I could use putty to get into my box then run Firefox by typing Firefox and the screen resolution (-x -y) and have it pull the window forward to my current machine all while keeping the history and whatnot on my Linux desktop.  Now that I  obfuscated the problem can anyone help me in figuring out what program was and how I could do it again.

Thanks,
Francis

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your home PC is a windows system. Since you want to run a program from a linux machine on your windows system, you need to install an X server like [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) on this machine.

Now after enabling X11Forwarding in your sshd config and in your putty connection, you can run programs like firefox from your Linux box on Windows.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely give that a try when I get home.